# PowerShell include SecureString in request header

Tags: powershell, api, rest, http-headers, securestring

Using PowerShell to retrieve an auth token for a set of APIs. The endpoint requires several headers, including a "secret", "id1", and "id2" among others.

- This auth token endpoint uses no explicit authentication method (i.e. Basic|Bearer|OAuth).
- The secret should be kept secret as any other password would be handled.
- Ideally, the script remains compatible with PowerShell-5.1, or 6, but it's not a requirement should there be no other way.

**How to include the secret in the header as `SecureString`, or other such format that similarly protects it?**

Code works when `$secret` is a plain old `String` type.

```
function Invoke-RestCall
{
    param
    (
        [Guid]$id1,
        [string]$id2
        [Security.SecureString]$clientSecret,
        #... other parameters for other headers
    )

    $uri = "https://..." #uri removed for public SO posting

    $headers = @{}
    $headers.Add("X-Id1", $id1)
    $headers.Add("X-Id2", $id2)
    $headers.Add("X-Secret", $clientSecret) # <-- how to convert from secure format?
    # other headers go here
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method GET -Headers $headers
    $response | ConvertTo-Json
}
```

A simple attempt at converting the secret to an encrypted string, such as

```
$headers.Add("X-Secret", (ConvertFrom-SecureString -Key $secret))
```

causes the call to return 400 Bad Request.

`SecureString` seems to be the most intuitive type to use. It's been a while since I worked with PowerShell so I'm not familiar with all the options. `PSCredential` and `NetworkCredential` seems like overkill but I'm still learning how to properly use them.

Comment: If you want to convert that securestring to plain text you can use `[System.Net.NetworkCredential]::new('', $clientSecret).Password` or if you have pwsh 7+ you can do `$clientSecret | ConvertFrom-SecureString -AsPlainText`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon that satisfies all my requirements, and works. Post as an answer and I'll mark it as so.

Comment: Note that while using https:// presumably protects your secret _during transport_, creating a plaint-text representation in a .NET string, however  briefly, is a point of vulnerability - see https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30612#issuecomment-523534346

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can structure your function so that the secret is passed as plain text, you can either use `[System.Net.NetworkCredential]::new('', $clientSecret).Password` if you're on Windows PowerShell 5.1 or if you have PowerShell 7+ you can also use `$clientSecret | ConvertFrom-SecureString -AsPlainText`.

Ideally, if your API supports more robust authentication methods you shouldn't use this one, but that's up to the API.

```
function Invoke-RestCall {
    param (
        [Guid] $id1,
        [string] $id2,
        [securestring] $clientSecret,
        [uri] $uri = "https://...",
        [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestMethod] $Method = 'GET'
        #... other parameters for other headers
    )

    $requestParams = @{
        Method  = $Method
        Uri     = $uri
        Headers = @{
            "X-Id1"    = $id1
            "X-Id2"    = $id2
            "X-Secret" = [System.Net.NetworkCredential]::new('', $clientSecret).Password
        }
    }

    Invoke-RestMethod @requestParams | ConvertTo-Json
}
```